# Change sending IP of only certain executable

Tags: tools, executable, packet, address

An executable that access the Internet uses my IP to do so. Is it be possible, with the help of a software or something like that, to change what IP an executable uses to access the Internet? Without the need to change/mask all my system's IP at once. The solution should be able to change a single executable IP, maybe a pack of executables would also work for me.

I have an executable that sends information to a host, and I need to open 2 or more instances of that executable and need they to reach the host with different IPs.

```
My IP -> qqq.qqq.qqq
Executable 1 -> xxx.xxx.xxx
Executable 2 -> yyy.yyy.yyy
```

Where Executable 1 and 2 can use proxy, IP that change all the time, doesn't matter -- they just need to reach the host with different IPs.

**Possible easy solution I read once:**
Create a virtual machine and use a proxy software  on it, programs from my main computer would use my IP, programs from virtual machine would use proxy software IP

But if i could avoid this solution, would be nicer.

Comment: What system are you using ? MS-Windows, Linux, MacOS X, other ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Following OP's other questions, assuming Windows OS*

This can be achieved with many 3rd-party solutions for Windows, choose the one which fits best to your needs:

**Proxifier**

> Proxifier allows network applications that do not support working
>   through proxy servers to operate through a SOCKS or HTTPS proxy and
>   chains.
>
> https://www.proxifier.com/

**ProcxyCap**

> ProxyCap enables you to redirect your computer's network connections
>   through proxy servers. You can tell ProxyCap which applications will
>   connect to the Internet through a proxy and under what circumstances.
>
> http://www.proxycap.com/

**ForceBindIP**

> ForceBindIP is a freeware Windows application that will inject itself
>   into another application and alter how certain Windows socket calls
>   are made, allowing you to force the other application to use a
>   specific network interface / IP address. This is useful if you are in
>   an environment with multiple interfaces and your application has no
>   option to bind to a specific interface.
>
> https://r1ch.net/projects/forcebindip

---

I used [Proxifier](https://www.proxifier.com/) in the past for gaming and torrenting purposes and it might be what you're searching for.

Comment: I need to open like, 10 executables, and put each one to work in a different IP

Comment: I'll be looking further to check witch one of these would be the best for my problem